# Structs and warnings C

Tags: c, struct

I have written a program that creates a list of 4 people using structs, then prints off the list of 4 people and the information that is provided. The program works, but I seem to get three warning. The warnings are for the same thing, and here they are

```
list.c:49:22: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
list.c:62:15: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
list.c:71:8: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
```

Below is my code, the C file first then the .h file

```
#include "list.h"

int main()
{
studentRec * root;
studentRec * secondStudent;
studentRec * thirdStudent;
studentRec * fourthStudent;
studentRec * printerStruct;

root = createStudent("Victor", "Filion", 5, 855755);
secondStudent = createStudent("Adam", "Sinclair", 5, 855756);
root = addToFront(root, secondStudent);

thirdStudent = createStudent("Anne", "Filion", 5, 855759);
root = addToFront(root, thirdStudent);

fourthStudent = createStudent("Eric", "Filion", 5, 855759);
root = addToFront(root, fourthStudent);

printerStruct = root;
printStruct(printerStruct);



free(root->firstName);
free(root->lastName);
free(root);
return (0);
 }

studentRec * createStudent(char * firstName, char * lastName, int GPA, int studentID)
{
studentRec * newStudent;

newStudent = malloc(sizeof(studentRec));
newStudent->firstName = malloc(sizeof(char *)*strlen(firstName));
strcpy(newStudent->firstName, firstName);
newStudent->lastName = malloc(sizeof(char *)*strlen(lastName));
strcpy(newStudent->lastName, lastName);
newStudent->GPA = GPA;
newStudent->studentID = studentID;
newStudent->next = NULL;
return(newStudent);
}

studentRec * addToFront(studentRec * root, studentRec * secondStudent)
{
secondStudent->next = root;
root = secondStudent;   
return(root);
}

void printStruct(studentRec * printStruct)
{
while(printStruct != NULL)
{
    printf("First Name: %s\n", printStruct->firstName);
    printf("Last Name: %s\n", printStruct->lastName);
    printf("GPA: %d\n", printStruct->GPA);
    printf("Student ID: %d\n", printStruct->studentID);
    printStruct = printStruct->next;
}
}

void deleteList(studentRec * root, studentRec * printStruct)
{
while(root != NULL)
{
    printStruct = root;
    root = printStruct->next;
    free(root->firstName);
    free(root->lastName);
    free(root);

}
}
```

This is my .h file

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
char * firstName;
char * lastName;
int studentID;
int GPA;
struct studentRec * next;
}studentRec;

studentRec * createStudent(char * firstName, char * lastName, int GPA, int studentID);
studentRec * addToFront(studentRec * root, studentRec * secondStudent);
void printStruct(studentRec * printStruct);
void deleteList(studentRec * root, studentRec * printStruct);
```

Comment: Which lines (in your code) are having problems? Also: your mallocs for strings don't include space for a 0 terminator.

Comment: `while(root != NULL)
{
    printStruct = root;
    root = printStruct->next;
    free(root->firstName);
    free(root->lastName);
    free(root);

}` --->>> `while(root)
{
    printStruct = root;
    root = printStruct->next;
    free(printstruct->firstName);
    free(printstruct->lastName);
    free(printstruct);

}`

Comment: Be careful when using [anonymous structs](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Unnamed-Fields.html) and `typedef`. Your structure has no name and thus you can't refer to it the way you do in the `next` field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT hold on  need a struct tag

In

```
typedef struct
{
char * firstName;
char * lastName;
int studentID;
int GPA;
struct studentRec * next;
}studentRec;
```

change the whole thing to

```
typedef struct studentRec_tag
{
char * firstName;
char * lastName;
int studentID;
int GPA;
struct studentRec_tag * next;
}studentRec;
```

you need to tag the struct since referencing it within itself

Comment: Or remove the typedef completely (which is simpler)